# Random Front-Page WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Saludos, quisiera saber si alguno de ustedes saben como hacer un front-page de forma random, es decir :

Tengo 4 tipos de Home

Home 1
Home 2
Home 3
Home 4

Al recargar la página principal que pueda cargar cualquiera de estos home de forma random.

Mil gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partir del anterior código logre dejarlo más completo para que no busque otra plantilla ( post / página ) :

```
      $rand = rand(1,4);
         if ($rand>=1&&$rand<=4){
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'perfil-'.$rand );
         }else {
          get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
      }
```

Comment: ¿y sí funcionó? entonces deberías marcar tu respuesta como correcta ;-)

Comment: Si funcionó @JesúsFranco

Answer (score 3):

En tu template front-page.php deberias hacer algo asi:

```
$rand = rand(1,4);

switch($rand){

    case 1:
        get_template_part('template1');
    break;

    case 2:
        get_template_part('template2');
    break;

    case 3:
        get_template_part('template3');
    break;

    case 4:
        get_template_part('template4');
    break;

}
```

Comment: Me funciona lo que me compartes, sin embargo esta funcionalidad busca el post o alguna página, hace random con otra selección aparte de las 4, como borre todos los post y páginas me genera un error cuando elige otro home aparte de los 4.

Answer (score 2):

Extendiendo lo anterior, puedes usar la función [wp_list_pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/), dónde le pasas como parámetro que el post_status = 'publish'.
De esa forma puedes sacar solo las páginas publicadas, o aplicar otros filtros por categoría, autor etc etc
Una vez tienes el listado, utilizas sizeof para saber la cantidad de páginas devueltas y con eso tiras el random como parámetro de limite superior, de 1 hasta X..

Comment: Hola @webdevrloping. Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por tu aporte. Creo que esta respuesta se podría beneficiar enormemente con un breve fragmento de código para ejemplificar lo que estás diciendo.